# How can I get or access to the value typed in the Div markup bokeh widget in Python environment?

Tags: python, html, widget, bokeh

I have a Div markup bokeh widget in python defined as:

```
self.text_input1 = Div(text="""<div class="SearchBar">
        <input type="text" id="TextInput_input" name="Text Input*" class="input" required/>
        <label class="label" for="Text Input*">Text Input*</label>
        <span class="guide-text">Only a-z, A-Z, 0-9, spaces, -, _, / and : can be used</span>
        </div>""")
```

I want to get the value that I typed in the text_input1 in Python. How can I get or access this value in python. I tried many CustomJS callback, but I could not access to this value in python.

As I see, by checking Inspect related to this widget, in the "input", tab "properties", the "value" keep the text which I typed ...[image]